# Python search all XML elements using regex

Tags: python, xml

I have a large tree with many nested elements and I am trying to recursively search all elements using regex and return a match count.  There are quite a few XML python modules - could anyone suggest a good starting place?

Comment: You will probably regret searching through an XML file using regex. It will probably save you a lot of pain to use a library to deal with XML files. Python has a few of these. For instance: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonXml

Comment: don't    do     this   !!!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).
I used it before, and it works pretty well for me.

You may traverse the XML tree, and use your regex patterns to filter the nodes.